# Pdf document is not downloading using copy link url

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts

I have used below query string (download=1) to download all documents but pdf is not downloading with the same query string.

https://sample.sharepoint.com/:b:/r/sites/Samplesite/SampleLibrary/sample.pdf?download=1

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about using https://xx.sharepoint.com/:b:/r/sites/xx/xx/xx.pdf?web=0 ?

Comment: No still it's not downloading